# Matriz de relaciones entre múltiples variables categóricas - R

Tags: r

Tengo 400 variables categóricas con sus 40 mil filas (observaciones), definidas todas por los niveles SI / NO. 
¿Cual sería la forma mas sencilla en R de crear una matriz que muestre de las 400 variables las que están relacionadas y las que no?

Entiendo que en principio lo suyo sería hacer un chi-cuadrado por pares y crear una matriz "de correlaciones" pero en lugar de correlaciones mostrar los p-values, aunque no sabría como hacerlo.

*Por otra parte intenté hacer un análisis de correspondencias, pero al ser tan grande no me dejaba "trabajar con un vector mayor a 18gb"

Espero haberme explicado correctamente

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si limitamos tu pregunta al aspecto netamente de programación y no al estadístico (que ciertamente no domino) podríamos decir que lo que buscas es aplicar un `chisq.test()` a todas las combinaciones de dos variables de tu matriz o `data,frame` y obtener por cada una de estas, el `p.value` correspondiente. Suponiendo un ejemplo similar a lo que planteas, pero más pequeño a efectos didácticos:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Si","No"), 300, replace = TRUE),ncol=3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df)

  X1 X2 X3
1 Si No No
2 No No No
3 Si No Si
4 Si Si No
5 No Si No
6 Si Si No
```

Generar las combinaciones de todas las variables, puede hacerse así:

```
relaciones <- combn(colnames(df), 2, simplify=FALSE)
relaciones

[[1]]
[1] "X1" "X2"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X3"

[[3]]
[1] "X2" "X3"
```

Con esto, podemos "aplicar" el `chisq.test()` a cada combinación y quedarnos solo con el `p.value` y por ejemplo `statistic`:

```
datos <- sapply(relaciones, 
                  FUN = function(x){
                    t <- chisq.test(df[,x[[1]]], df[,x[[2]]])
                    cbind(t$p.value, t$statistic)
                    },
                  simplify = TRUE
                  )
```

y por último, organizamos los resultados en un `data.frame` para tenerlos más cómodos:

```
resultados <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, relaciones))
resultados$p.value <- datos[1, ]
resultados$statistic <- datos[2, ]

resultados

  X1 X2   p.value  statistic
1 X1 X2 0.8505811 0.03548589
2 X1 X3 0.4343294  0.6112185
3 X2 X3 0.7406568  0.1095502
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias. *Hay un "reultados" al final.

Comment: Tengo una duda, veo que con $p.value obtienes dicho valor, si lo cambio por $statistic obtendría el X^2, ¿Si quisiera los dos como reformularia el código?

Comment: @Aibloy, revisa mi última edición. Saludos.